# Show/hide div when checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript

I would like to show/hide a div when a single checkbox is selected. It currently works with "Select all" but I can't get it to work with a single checkbox. Here's the code for "Select All":

**JS:**

```
<script language='JavaScript'> 
var checkboxcount = 1;

function doCheckOne() {
    if(checkboxcount == 0) {
        with (document.messageform) {
            for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                if (elements[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                    elements[i].checked = false;
                document.getElementById('mail_delete_button').style.display = "none";
                }
            }
            checkboxcount = checkboxcount + 1;
        }
    } else
    with (document.messageform) {
        for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if (elements[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                elements[i].checked = true;
            document.getElementById('mail_delete_button').style.display = "block";
            }
        }
    checkboxcount = checkboxcount - 1;
    }
}
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="doCheckAll();this.blur();">Select all</a>
<div id="mail_delete_button" style="display: none;"></div>
```

I'd like to display the div "mail_delete_button" when a single checkbox is selected and hide it when there's nothing checked. Note: My html/input field is in the form "messageform" This is my input code:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='delete_convos[]' value='{$pms[pm_loop].pmconvo_id}'>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks! :)

Comment: Please indent your code, it makes things much easier to read.

Comment: Any reason why you're not using jQuery?

Comment: @JakubKonecki: Maybe it's a lightweight project.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! @minitech Sorry first post, thought I did indent it. How would I format this for jQuery?

Comment: When you talk about a "single checkbox", are you saying your form has multiple checkboxes and you want the div to be displayed only when one or more of those checkboxes is checked? Perhaps you could make a simple demo at http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Yes it works fine with "Select All" using the code above but I also want the div to show when one or more box is selected!

Comment: If I understand it, you want to attach onclick event to each checkbox, so that when it is clicked, the div will appear? Oh yeah, this probably needs traversing the whole form.

Comment: Yes @Stano, I'm using a {section} to loop the messages in the inbox, each message will have a checkbox beside it... I'd like it if a single box is checked to display the div. I'll try and make a demo...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Gave the checkbox an `id="chk"`

```
<input type='checkbox' name='delete_convos[]' value='{$pms[pm_loop].pmconvo_id}' id="chk">

document.getElementById("chk").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('mail_delete_button').style.display = this.checked ? "block" : "none";
}​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GJG87/2/)

Comment: Thanks @sachleen, for some reason I can't get this to work... I also tried adding an "onclick" to the input. Any suggestions?

Comment: (Not related to whether it will work for the OP, but) A suggestion to pretty-up the code: `document.getElementById('mail_delete_button').style.display = this.checked ? "block" : "none";`

Comment: Thanks @nnnnnn... The code/demo works but not in my document?

Comment: Good suggestion @nnnnnn. davec, the code in the demo works.. share your implementation of it so we can see what doesn't.

Comment: checking/unchecking any one of those causes the button to show/hide. how do you want it to be different.

Comment: Thanks @Stano... because my messages are in a {section} loop I will only have 1 checkbox input field in my html which loops and is displayed beside each message. The problem isn't with the code, just getting it to work within a loop. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Imho you can use the solution as in this answer, something like:  <input type='checkbox' name='delete_convos[]' value='{$pms[pm_loop].pmconvo_id}' onclick="updateMDBstatus()"> , you don't need to create addEventListeners dynamically. There should be no problems.

Comment: Sachleen is right: Davec, if you want some help, "share your implementation of it so we can see what doesn't."

Comment: Hard to post an example because I'm using a {section} loop, reads from database etc.. sorry I'm doing my best, confusing!! :) I got @sachleen's example to work but only on the first "looped" check box... other boxes don't show/hide the div! Thanks guys!!

Comment: Oh and it only show/hides the div after clicking 2 times. I also had to add an "onclick" to make it work...

Answer (score 0):

This may help someone using jQuery. You can show and hide div blocks based on the checked checkbox using jQuery’s [toggle()](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method. The div blocks in the following example are hidden by default using the CSS `display` property, which is set to `none`.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
      var val = $(this).attr("value");
      $("." + val).toggle();
    });
  });
```

You can see an example here: [How to show/hide DIV if checkbox selected](https://stackhowto.com/how-to-show-hide-div-if-checkbox-selected/)